# Is there a metadata table(s) in oracle that stores user defined types?

Tags: oracle, types, metadata

If someone does something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE some_type AS OBJECT(whatever NUMBER);
```

and then I do something like:

```
SELECT type_name FROM some_magic_table WHERE type_name = 'some_type';
```

should i reasonably expect oracle to work like this?

I don't wish to rely on Oracle SQL Developer interface to eyeball types all the time, that's why.

I am using 10g btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called USER_TYPES (I guess a SYS view).

Try this(if the type was created by the schema/user running this query):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_types 
 WHERE type_name = 'SOME_TYPE';
```

To look into TYPES that you have access to irrespetive of the schema:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM all_types 
 WHERE type_name = 'SOME_TYPE';
```

Comment: As an aside, it IS possible to have type names in lower or mixed case.

Comment: @DCookie: Indeed, but I think the data dictinary views always return the names in Upper case.

Comment: no, try it: `create type "AbcDef" as table of number; select * from user_types where type_name = 'AbcDef';`

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thx. I have tested it and it indeed works. Updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 5):

```
--
-- The types
--
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_TYPES

--
-- Their attributes
--
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_TYPE_ATTRS
```